# Sockets on Windows 7, can't connect

Tags: python, sockets, windows-7

Trying to create my first client-server application, I came across an error. This code is exactly the same as in the documentation, but I have problems.

Server:

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9090

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break

print data
conn.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9090
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall('Hello, world')
s.close()
```

After execution, I don't see the message `print Connected by, addr` and `print data` in the server part.

I use Windows 7, Komodo Firewall (I tried to close the firewall, but it didn't solve the problem), Avast Antivirus, Python 2.7.

Very interesting, that there are no errors, but the output just doesn't work.

Also, my server application just freezes until the client connects to the server. Can this be solved just using threading?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! It's nice that you start working with sockets! However, if you are new to sockets AND to threading, there is just too much to comment on about your code. May I suggest you take a look at: twisted http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/. An event driven Framework which will hanbdle the threading for you! It's really easy to use!

Comment: Framework for wimps =) Actually,sockets do not look too complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to Cfreak. Basically what is happening with data is that it is getting assigned an empty string which causes the loop to break. So putting the print statement in the loop fixes the problem. Assuming you need to access that data after the loop terminates try something like

```
data = []
while True:
    datum = conn.recv(1024)
    data.append(datum)
    if not datum: break

print " ".join(data)
```

Here is the code I am running and my computer, and it works

client

```
import socket
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9090
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall('Hello, world')
s.close()
```

server

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9090

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
data = []
while True:
    datum = conn.recv(1024)
    data.append(datum)
    if not datum: break

print " ".join(data)

conn.close()
```

so I don't think it is a problem with your code... if you have a machine without a firewall/antivirus on it try the program on that machine.

Comment: **johnthexiii** , i tried your version, the same problem. Actually,problem,maybe,here "**conn, addr = s.accept()**" because string "print '**Connected by', addr**" i don`t see,and this code is before loop

Comment: @progerz the fact that you are not seeing the connection print statement makes me think that this is a problem with your computer.

Comment: i also think,that it is problem with computer... Very strange problem... In the morning(12 hrs ago) all works fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to `accept()` and `print` inside the loop. (or use two loops). I'm not very familiar with socket programming in Python but I'm guess it would look something like this. (completely untested!)

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected by', addr

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data: 
            break

        print data
    conn.close()
```